# Woocommerce Wp all import Dynamic pricing issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Bulk Pricing for WooCommerce for the dynamic pricing but my problem is I cannot insert data from csv using wp all import, because the field is array with one meta key.

**Here's what it looks like when I inset data in the fields and the database:**

1, Insert data in fields manualy.   [image: img1]

2. How it looks like in the database. [image: img2]

**But when I tried to use wp all import, this is what happens. (I will update the old data using wp all import)**

1. I Change the default value from "10" to csv element (red underline)
2. This is what happen in the database.

---

I need to use wp all import for importing csv and wp lab for the dynamic pricing, I will be importing more than 50 product without changing the dynamic pricing each. if you have any suggestions that would be better

---